# Renaming value if it has similar text in the string (Fuzzy Grouping)

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

I'm trying to use Power Query to detect similar text in a column and rename any columns with additional text or characters in to a stripped down version of the same text.  Is it possible to do this without the use of a reference column in another table?

Example below, the column on the left is the mixed array of names, the column on the right is what I'd like for the output to be.

[image]

Comment: Please don't paste pictures of data

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But you'll have to experiment with different `Threshold` values. The default will probably not work on your data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Table.FuzzyGroup() to achieve what you need. It isn't available from the UI in Excel or PowerBI but is available as a function to call.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-fuzzygroup

Comment: Thank you, Table.FuzzyGroup() did not answer the question but I learned more about the "fuzzy" options available in PQ.  The Table.AddFuzzyClusterColumn worked well for me!

Comment: Both approaches work. If you'd supplied data as copiable text, I'd have shown you how. Don't forget to mark as solved - thanks.